# Write the last 5 accepted result on a text file in FORTRAN

Tags: text, io, fortran

I am going to write code in Fortran which keeps the last 5 accepted results on a text file. How can I do that? it should be noted that I need the last 2000 results, for example if I have 200 results I need to keep the last 5 and delete the first results. here it is a example code

```
program test
implicit none
REAL :: r
integer :: i
     open(1000,file='results.txt',status='unknown')


     do i=1,100000  
     CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(r) 
     print*, r


     if(r .lt. 5E-01 .and. r .gt. 4E-01)then

        write(1000,*) r
      endif
end do
    close(1000)

end program test
```

Comment: Open the file in, fill a look-a-head buffer of 5, read until end of file. Close the file in. Open a file out. Flush your look-a-head buffer of 5 to file out. Close the file out. Open the file out for reading. Open the file in for writing. Read from file out, write to file in. Close file out. Close file in. Delete file out. End program.

Answer (score 0):

incomplete / pseudo code

```
start process loop

process...

if (accepted) then
  a(1) = a(2)
  a(2) = a(3)
  a(3) = a(4)
  a(4) = a(5)
  a(5) = new
end if

end process loop

write (*, *) a
```

Comment: Or `a(1:4) = a(2:5); a(5) = new`. Or `a = eoshift(a,1,boundary=new)`.

Comment: i think he means to continuously update the file. In that case, simply rewrite the entire file each time you get a hit.